# How to get a list of the playlists and songs in an iPhone/iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

Can I get a list of the playlists and songs in each playlist in an iPhone? This is for a legal app. so hidden APIs/jailbroken solutions don't apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for 3.0, currently it is not possible. The 3.0 API is currently considered confidential by Apple, so that I probably should not say more, but You can read the API details on the website.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with the 2.x public APIs, and the 3.x is under a NDA, so it can't be discussed here.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that while the 3.0 API is under NDA, it *has* been publicly announced that one of the new features is interaction with the user's iTunes library.