# how to get list of all the songs in ipodLibrary in an Array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i get songs from my iphone's ipod to my application in array in iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221955/how-can-i-get-songs-from-my-iphones-ipod-to-my-application-in-array-in-iphone-s)

```
NSMutableArray *collectionMutableCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myMediaItemCollection.items];
```

i want to get the list of all the songs which are there in my ipod in an array is the above code right ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [MPMediaPickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Take a look on this tutorial : [Tuto](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-music-library-access/)